# Combine multiple arrays to a single with fields

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
first_list      = [1,2,3,4]
second_list     = ['a','b','c']
```

How can I combine these two arrays to a single one with two fields ?

```
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  c = _ref[_i];
  mList.push({
    clients: c
  });
}
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref2.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  c = _ref2[_i];
  mList.push({
    projects: c
  });
}
```

I tried this but it's just adding objects to the array instead of having an object item with two properties.

I have

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]
         |        |        |       |       |      |        |
      clients   clients clients clients project project  project
```

while I'd like to have :

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]
         |        |        |       |      
      clients   clients clients clients
         +         +      +        +
      projects   projects projects  projects(null)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3s8rasm6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over both array in one. The `||` operator does that if the value is undefined it will ne replaced with null

```
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  mList.push({
    clients: _ref[_i] || null,
    project: _ref2[_i] || null
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use both the objects together. https://jsfiddle.net/y19fstp7/

```
mList      = []
first_list = [1,2,3,4];
second_list = ['a','b','c'];

var c, _i, _len, _ref,_ref2;
_ref = first_list;
_ref2 = second_list;
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  c = _ref[_i];
  mList.push({
    clients: _ref[_i],
    projects: _ref2[_i]
  });
}
console.log(mList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [lodash zipWith](https://lodash.com/docs#zipWith):

```
var first_list = [1,2,3,4];
var second_list = ['a','b','c'];

_.zipWith(first_list, second_list, function(first, second){
    return {
        clients:first || null, 
        project:second || null
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tna4dbeg/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var first_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
  var second_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  var clients = [];
  var projects = [];
  var combined = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < first_list.length; i++) {
    clients.push({
      client: first_list[i]
    });
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < second_list.length; i++) {
    projects.push({
      project: second_list[i]
    });
  }

  var length = Math.max(first_list.length, second_list.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    combined.push($.extend(clients[i], projects[i]));
  }


  console.log(clients);
  console.log(projects);
  console.log(combined);
});
```